# Sharing data between activitiesin Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, data-binding

I am programming an android app that does the following (in a nutshell):

1. Creates an activity that listens to data streaming in via bluetooth
2. Parses the data streamed in
3. (Plan) Display the interpreted meaning of the data, like a graph/text

For #3, I am planning to create a new activity that sits on top of the Bluetooth Streaming activity -- after all, the bluetooth matters should be in the background after initial set up.

However, I am having issues sending the data between the BlueTooth activity and the display activity.

I have googled, researched and the best I can come up with is using Intents for this, but its not working.

Here is an example. Say data is coming in and I interpret the data involve body movement:

```
private BodyMovementPositionStream() {
    if (getActivity() != null && getContext() != null && iDebug == null) {
        iDebug = new Intent(getActivity(), AGDebug.class);
        iDebug.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (theApplication.isD()) {
                    Log.d(theApplication.getTAG(), "Creating Intent for Position Debuging...");
                    getContext().registerReceiver(new AGDReceiver(), new IntentFilter("com.ekscsy.sleepstudy.debug.AGDebug"));
                    getContext().startActivity(iDebug);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

So basically, in that snip-it, I start the activity AGDebug, add the flags for new task, and then I register the receiver in a new thread. This works, I see it on my phone and the `Log.d()` message shows up.

Later on in my code, I extract the data:

```
    private static final int fSize = 4;
    public void unpack(byte[] data) {
        int i = -fSize;
        accx = Streams.byteArr2ByteBuff(data, i += fSize, fSize).order(null).getFloat();
        accy = Streams.byteArr2ByteBuff(data, i += fSize, fSize).order(null).getFloat();
        accz = Streams.byteArr2ByteBuff(data, i += fSize, fSize).order(null).getFloat();
        gyrox = Streams.byteArr2ByteBuff(data, i += fSize, fSize).order(null).getFloat();
        gyroy = Streams.byteArr2ByteBuff(data, i += fSize, fSize).order(null).getFloat();
        gyroz = Streams.byteArr2ByteBuff(data, i += fSize, fSize).order(null).getFloat();
        temp = Streams.byteArr2ByteBuff(data, i += fSize, fSize).order(null).getFloat();
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.ekscsy.sleepstudy.debug.AGDReceiver");
        intent.putExtra("com.ekscsy.sleepstudy.debug.AGDebug.accxF", accx);
        getContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

At the end of the extraction, I make a new intent, `.putExtra()` the name of the package + a float with some data. I do the `.sendBroadcast()` but... nothing happens. I have a breakpoint that never gets called:

```
public class AGDReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        assert(true); //breakpoint here
    }

}
```

Obviously, I am missing steps here, but I can't seem to find any good information on sharing data between activities.

In fact, let me re-iterate, the main goal here is the share data between activities. Data, being floats, ints, etc. I am assuming the "Android" way of doing this is through intents and broadcast, but if there is a better method, I am all ears.

I am looking to make this app compatible with API 8.

EDIT: FYI, I changed the code to take the start of the AGDebug activity out of its own thread. It looks more like this now:

```
    if (getActivity() != null && getContext() != null && iDebug == null) {
        iDebug = new Intent(getActivity(), AGDebug.class);
        iDebug.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        Log.d(theApplication.getTAG(), "Creating Intent for Position Debuging...");
        getContext().registerReceiver(new AGDReceiver(), new IntentFilter("com.ekscsy.sleepstudy.debug.AGDebug"));
        getContext().startActivity(iDebug);
    }
```

Still didn't change anything though. I thought  maybe there was an issue of running the activity between different manually created threads.

Major Update/New Problem:

I found this guide http://www.sohailaziz.com/2012/04/localbroadcastmanager-intra-application.html and was able to successfully implement its strategy of making the broadcaster work with the LocalBroadcastManager. However... and this is very weird... I am finding the `onReceieve()` method gets called sometimes or not. IOW: when I run the app, either it will get called each time I say `lbm.sendBroadcast(intent)` or it won't get called at all.

Very puzzling.

Final Edit:
Okay I got it to work. There is a delicate art of making sure each intent is named correctly and points to the right spot. Once done, it seems to be consistent.

Comment: If you have figured it out, you should answer your own question and accept it. Otherwise this question ends up on the "unanswered" list. Or, you could just accept my answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You register the broadcast receiver like this:

```
getContext().registerReceiver(new AGDReceiver(),
    new IntentFilter("com.ekscsy.sleepstudy.debug.AGDebug"));
```

but you broadcast this Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.ekscsy.sleepstudy.debug.AGDReceiver");
```

The actions in the Intents are not the same. You could have saved yourself this trouble if you defined a constant for this, ie:

```
public static final String MY_INTENT_ACTION = "com.ekscsy.sleepstudy.debug.AGDReceiver";
```

and then used that constant when you create the broadcast intent and when you create the intent filter for registering the broadcast receiver.

Comment: Although I did manage to get it figured out through this guide (http://www.sohailaziz.com/2012/04/localbroadcastmanager-intra-application.html) your answer hit a major nail. I didn't use the same package and class name -- I got confused in separating the intents for the receiver and the activity.