# Dynamically updating data between android app activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I recently had a question ([Sharing data between activitiesin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093639/android-sharing-data-between-activities)) where I solved a part of my problem, but I am still having issues. I decided to start completely fresh.

This simple app does the following things:

1. Starts a main activity which immediately calls a "DataActivity" during its onCreate() method
2. DataActivity only increments a number, creates a bundle, stuffs the number in that bundle, and shoots it off into the LocalBroadcastManager inside of an intent.
3. MainActivity picks that new number back up and updates its ListView.

Now, my problems lie here:

- (Fixed) The intent is not being broadcasted! (It worked in my last app but its completely not working here)
- I'm not sure how to make sure the MainActivity's list is on the top of the display
- I'm not sure how to "minimize" the DataActivity

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DataActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("First", true);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter iff = new IntentFilter(MainActivity.class.getCanonicalName());
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Creating Intent for Position Debuging...");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(AGDReceiver, iff);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(AGDReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private volatile ArrayAdapter<Integer> aradInt;
    public BroadcastReceiver AGDReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final int broadcast = intent.getExtras().getInt("iInt");
            Bundle b = intent.getExtras().getBundle("bBundle");
            final int bI = b.getInt("bInt");
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onReceieve(): " + broadcast);
            initArrAd();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "runOnUiThread(): " + broadcast);
                    aradInt.add(broadcast);
                    aradInt.setNotifyOnChange(true);
                    aradInt.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

        }

    };

    private void initArrAd() {
        if (aradInt == null) {
            aradInt = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this.getApplicationContext(),R.id.listView1);
        }
    }

}
```

DataActivity.java

```
public class DataActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_data);
    }

    private volatile int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onResume(): " + count);
        count++;
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.class.getCanonicalName());
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("bInt", count);
        intent.putExtra("iInt", count);
        intent.putExtra("bBundle", b);
        this.moveTaskToBack(true);
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcastSync(intent);
            intent.removeExtra("iInt");
            intent.removeExtra("bInt");
            intent.putExtra("bInt", count++);
            intent.putExtra("iInt", count);
        }
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onResume(): Done");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.data, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

As for updating the ListView, I figure once I consistently get the data where I want it and the view for the MainActivity is visible, that should be trivial.

And just in case, my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.eks.mytestbed"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.eks.mytestbed.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.eks.mytestbed.DataActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_data" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

UPDATE: It looks like the Broadcast aspect of the question is down (I needed to put the unregister calls in the .onDestroy() method instead of .onPause() ), but updating the listview on the MainActivity is not working!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you haven't register your `BroadcastReceiver`. You must register a receiver to use it and thus you have to unregister it when finished.

As you have used LocalBroadcastReceiver so

To Register

```
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
            AGDReceiver ,
            new IntentFilter(INTENT_FILTER_NAME));
```

To Unregister

```
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(
            AGDReceiver );
```

and another thing is your aradLong is not initialized

Comment: another tips, better follow the naming convention. start a instance's name with small letter

Comment: Hmm I implemented that and it still isn't working. The BroadcastReceiver isn't getting called.

Comment: I do admit, I forgot to put the registration in there, but still... no go.

Comment: send broadcast  using the intent which is using the same name as you registered.. in my example i used FILTER_NAME

Comment: I am doing that. The name I am using is "MainActivity.class.getCanonicalName()" which equates to com.eks.mytestbed.MainActivity. Could you be more clear? Thanks

Comment: plsae add the updated code where you have register and unregister the receiver

Comment: I did update the code... Unfortunately there are no line numbers on here so I will say the register is in MainActivity.onResume(). I didn't implement the unregister is in MainActivity.onPause(). Hmm, I wonder what would happen if I put the unregister in .onDestroy() instead... trying now

Comment: Okay that seemed to work! But now the part about runOnUiThread() and updating the listview with it isn't! Its causing a crash

Comment: aradLong is not initialized

Comment: Boy.. am I just making every newb mistake or what. Let me initialize and get back to you!

Comment: Okay I got the errors to go away and runOnUiThread() functions, but the list never shows up! I put this.moveTaskToBack(true) in DataActivity.onResume() but all that seemed to do was cause my whole app to turn off after it was finished.